# Conditional Formatting alternate rows and matching rows in Excel

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to apply conditional formatting to my data where I need to color the rows based on certain columns. If the current and previous rows have same data in 4 particular columns, I will color those rows. But I also need to apply this color to alternate rows.

So the result I need is like the format in the image below:

[image]

As in the sample image above, first two rows have same values in column Name1, Name2, Type_Name and Type_Code, they are colored. Then, the next row is skipped from coloring. And then the next row even if it does not have a matching row above or below, it will be colored. Then rows with Rita in Name1 are skipped.

So far I'm able to get to the rows with same values in the 4 columns and color the alternate rows, both the logics separately, but unable to apply the mix of both properly. Below are the logics applied so far.

1. This one, where the rows have same values in the 4 required columns, using the formula

   =OR($H2&$I2&$J2&$K2 = $H1&$I1&$J1&$K1, $H2&$I2&$J2&$K2 = $H3&$I3&$J3&$K3)

[image]

2. And alternate rows colored with the formula

   =MOD(ROW( ),2)=0

[image]

Comment: You could use `Concat($H2:$K2)` to simplify the equation a little :)

Comment: I agree to your point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first add a helper column which separates the groups.

This is done by checking if the relevant columns of the row is the same as the row above. If it is, we simply take the max value of the column, if it is different, we increment the max value by 1. We can then apply the conditional formatting if this helper column is an odd value:

[image]

Comment: Agreed, a helper column really helps. Otherwise maybe only VBA can do this.

Comment: @newacc2240 I feel that there is probably a way to do it directly with conditional formatting. A helper column just makes it so much quicker and simpler. Leave it with me and I will see what I can do.

Comment: My first thought was it has to be traced back to the first data. However after reading your answer, maybe a `sumproduct` will help.

Comment: Any reason you can't combine the formulas in the conditional formatting? Like this `=ISODD(IF(AND(A1-A2,B1=B2,C1=C2,D1=D2),MAX($G$1:$G1),MAX($G$1:$G1)+1))` Edit: Never mind

Comment: @seadoggie01 When it looks for the MAX value in the helper column, it won't be there...

Comment: Wow, I could not think of that Helper Column. Will I be able to put this Helper column in a separate sheet (hidden, may be), pre-calculated per the columns in the main sheet. The columns in the main sheet will be fixed for sure. I want to hide the Helper Column since this data is a report which I need to share.

Comment: Yes, you could. You just need to update the formulas accordingly. Rather than moving it to another sheet, I would suggest just moving it to the far right of the same sheet and hiding the column and setting the print area not to include it.

Comment: Thats a gr8 idea too. Thank you