# Conditional formatting to range when values in column changes

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to set a complex `conditional formatting` in range `B2:F8` with this logic (without using a helper column):

**Option1:**
When values in `column C` change, change color until next change of value in `C`, alternating between two colors.

**Option2:**
If this is too difficult at least set the previous row where C changes, with a color.

This is my current attempt that is only changing the row 2.

[image]

My option1 output would be like this
[image]

My option2 output would be like this
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional Formatting alternate rows and matching rows in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52555214/conditional-formatting-alternate-rows-and-matching-rows-in-excel)

Comment: Not really, since I'm trying to get a solution without using a helper column. Thanks